# Bring layered, moused over image to forefront

Tags: css

I have 8 images layered over each other (in kid of a cascade design).  When any 1 of those 8 images is moused over, it need to come to the forefront of the other images and be resized so that it covers the cascade behind it.

I figured out how to resize the image when moused over, but I don't know how to bring it in front of the other images.

HTML:

```
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="apDiv1"><img src="images/redballoons.jpg" width="800" height="600"> </div>
            <div id="apDiv2"><img src="images/orangeballoons.jpg" width="800" height="600">              </div>  
            <div id="apDiv3"><img src="images/yellowballoons.jpg" width="800" height="600"></div>
            <div id="apDiv4"><img src="images/greenballoons.jpg" width="800" height="600"></div>
            <div id="apDiv5"><img src="images/blueballoons.jpg" width="800" height="600"></div>
            <div id="apDiv6"><img src="images/purpleballoons.jpg" width="800" height="600"></div>
            <div id="apDiv7"><img src="images/whiteballoons.jpg" width="800" height="600"></div>
            <div id="apDiv8"><img src="images/blackballoons.jpg" width="800" height="600"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body 
{
background-color: #00CCFF;
margin-top: 15pt;
margin-bottom: 15pt;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-left: 10%;
}

img
{
border: 5px solid;
}

img:hover
{
transform: scale(1.75)
}

#apDiv1
{
position: absolute;
width: 800px;
height: 600px;
z-index: 1;
left: 125px;
top: 15px;
}

#apDiv2
{
position: absolute;
width: 800px;
height: 600px;
z-index: 2;
left: 175px;
top: 65px;
}
```

...and so on with 6 more apDivs.

Comment: Give a common class to your `div`s (like `apDiv`) so you don't repeat yourself in CSS code so much.

Answer (score 0):

Give the hovered-over image a higher `z-index` value than anything else likely to cover it.

To be on the very safe side, add `z-index: 9999;` to your `img:hover` rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
img:hover{
z-index: 100;
}
```

Ensure the z-index on the hovered img is higher than the rest, this will bring it to the front.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#apDiv1").css("z-index", "9999");
```

Or in CSS:

```
img:hover
{
transform: scale(1.75);
z-index: 9999;
}
```